# Difference quotient computation of $x^{1/4}$.

Tags: calculus

I'm a bit stuck doing this. I understand the answer should be $\frac{x^{-3/4}}{4}$ , but I am unable to find it using first principle. I get to $$\frac{(x+h)^{1/4} - x^{1/4}}{h}$$ but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: lhopital EASY @Arthur

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Are you sure you need to do that? It seems rather complicated. The best I can think of suggesting is: Does your book show how to deduce the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$, and can that be adapted?

Answer (score 4):

There's a sneaky trick called Taking the Conjugate. I assumed you covered this in rationalizing the denominator? Well, in this case, we rationalise the numerator.

Let $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{4}}$.

$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} &= \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{(x+h)^{\frac{1}{4}} - x^{\frac{1}{4}}}{h}\\
&= \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\left ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{4}} - x^{\frac{1}{4}} \right ) \left ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{4}} + x^{\frac{1}{4}} \right )}{h\left ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{4}} + x^{\frac{1}{4}} \right )}\\
&= \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{(x+h)^{\frac{1}{2}} - x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{h \left ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{4}} + x^{\frac{1}{4}} \right )}\\
&= \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\left ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{2}} - x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right )\left ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{2}} + x^{\frac{1}{2}} \right )}{h\left ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{4}} + x^{\frac{1}{4}}\right )\left ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{2}} + x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right )}\\
&= \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{(x+h)-x}{h\left ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{4}} + x^{\frac{1}{4}}\right )\left ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{2}} + x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right )}\\
&= \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{h}{h\left ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{4}} + x^{\frac{1}{4}}\right )\left ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{2}} + x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right )}\\
&= \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{1}{\left ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{4}} + x^{\frac{1}{4}}\right )\left ((x+h)^{\frac{1}{2}} + x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right )}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\left (x^{\frac{1}{4}}+x^{\frac{1}{4}}\right ) \left (x^{\frac{1}{2}}+x^{\frac{1}{2}} \right )}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\left (2x^{\frac{1}{4}} \right ) \left (2x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right )}\\
&= \frac{1}{4x^{\frac{3}{4}}}\\
&= \frac{1}{4} x^{-\frac{3}{4}}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\frac{(x+h)^\frac14 - x^\frac14}{h} &= \frac{(x+h)^\frac12 - x^\frac12}{h((x+h)^\frac14 + x^\frac14)} \\
&= \frac{(x+h) - x}{h((x+h)^\frac14 + x^\frac14)((x+h)^\frac12 + x^\frac12)} \\
&= \frac{1}{((x+h)^\frac14 + x^\frac14)((x+h)^\frac12 + x^\frac12)}
\end{align}

Now, let $h \to 0$.

Comment: I would probably simplify the fraction a bit before letting $h\to 0$, but this seems like the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x+h)^{1/n}=a$ and $x^{1/n}=b$

$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(x+h)^{1/n}-x^{1/n}}h$$

$$=\lim_{a\to b} \dfrac{a-b}{a^n-b^n}=\cdots=\dfrac1{nb^{n-1}}$$ as $a\to b, a-b\ne0$

Replace the value of $b$

Comment: How did you get the last step, with a-b and $a^n - b^n$?

Comment: @JoaoNoch,  for $a\ne b$ $$\dfrac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}a^rb^{n-1-r}$$  Now set $a\to b$

Comment: I see now. Thank you.